# Problems trying to inject dependencies into Global Filter using Structuremap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, structuremap

So I talked briefly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849822/trying-to-figure-out-an-elegant-way-to-persist-data-between-objects-in-asp-net-m) about how I have a global filter that runs `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyFilter)` and obtains a subdomain manager which will conduct some database look up based on subdomain information.

My goal was to have the filtercontext.result set to a new ResultRedirect object if the validations I am conducting fails.  However, if it is successful, this Subdomain manager object will persist in the Structuremap Container for the remainder of the request.

Originally I had believed that the controller object was not instantiated when the global filters ran so I had expected to populate a subdomain object property on the controller based on the results of this subdomain manager.

However, I have two delemma's:

1. I believe the controller has been instantiated when the global filter runes, so even if the global controller that runs the subdomain manager and validates the request is validated, I can't populate the subdomain object on the on my controller from the subdomain manager object that is in the container
2. Secondly, and more largely, I can't seem to find a valid way to inject dependencies into my Global filter (SomeValidationAttribute : ActionAttribute) using structuremap.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

1) Stick with a simple dependecy in the constructur of the controller and maybe inject it in the BeginExecute. But I do think you will have to describe what you really is trying to archive, and not let us guess along with your solution.

2) Register your GlobalFilterProvider

```
public class StructureMapGlobalFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public StructureMapGlobalFilterProvider(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    private IContainer _container;

    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor 

actionDescriptor)
    {
        return new List<Filter>();
    }
}
```

Source: http://thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/2/3/structuremap-global-action-filters-and-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 0):

`GetFilters` of `FilterAttributeFilterProvider` returns zero item for global filters. In this special case, define your global filter using the StructureMap's container:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(container.GetInstance<LogAttribute>());
```

And then you need to inject StructureMap's `IContainer` to your filter as well:

```
public class LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IContainer _container; 
    public LogAttribute(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        _container.GetInstance<ILogActionService>().Log("......data......");
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Without calling `_container.GetInstance`, all of the dependencies of a global filter, will be instantiated only one time, at the beginning of the program.